# Leave UK with second EU passport, return with UK passport?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality

To save time at border controls can I Leave the UK with another EU passport, and return with my UK passport?

Answer (score 2):

If flying, you don't leave the UK on any passport, as there are no exit formalities.

If travelling by train or sea, the carrier will do an exit check - in this case your other EU passport will do, as EU citizens have freedom of movement.

And what does Brexit have to do with this? It won't happen until 2019 (most likely).

In any case, you'll be fine.

Comment: Well UK people are waiting in massive queues in Schengen zones as we speak. 2019 is very close for me as I'll still be young enough to enjoying travel then.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Nothing's changed yet - you're still EU citizens and can use the EU queues, and be admitted indefinitely with no questions asked.

Comment: `If flying, you don't leave the UK on any passport, as there are no exit formalities.` Airlines do submit Advance Passenger Information to the UK government. Similar to flying out of the US. That piece of information can help to see whether a person has overstayed or not. However, as this concerns a British Citizen, practically, nobody will or can do anything.

Comment: @kiradotee Plus entries by land are not recorded in the first place (other than through the entry stamp most non-EU/EFTA citizens get)

Comment: @Crazydre even though when travelling by land they do both entry and exit checks? It's still not recorded?

Comment: @kiradotee It's not, as I requested a copy of my entry/exit record a while ago, and only air entries/exits were listed whatsoever, which was also not generated during border control, but through airline API.

Comment: @Crazydre that's interesting and weird they don't record them! Thanks.